# How to prove that the maximum solution of different power of p of elements s.t. unit $\ell_2$-norm constraint exists when $x_i<x_j$ if $p_i<p_j$?

Tags: proof-writing, normed-spaces, lp-spaces, solution-verification, provability

I am trying to prove the following thing.

---

Suppose $x_i$ satisfies the following equation,

(0) $\sum_{i=1}^{L}{x_i^2}=1$ where $x_i\ge0, L\in \mathbb{N}$.

Then, the solution of maximizing $\sum_{i=1}^{L}{x_{i}^{p_i}}$ under condition of ($1< p_i < p_j <2, \,1\le i < j <L$) exists when $x_i<x_j$.

---

I was tried to prove this by using Lagrangian multipliers but I stuck to the following a (3) step.

(1) Lagrangian function:
$\mathcal{L}=\sum_{1}^{L}{x_{i}^{p_i}}+\lambda(\sum_{1}^{L}{x_i^2}-1$)

(2) $\partial\mathcal{L}/\partial x_i=0$ $\rightarrow$ $x_i=\left(\frac{-p_i}{2\lambda}\right)^\frac{1}{2-p_i}$

(3) Substituting (2) into (0), $\lambda=?$

It would be really nice to let me know how to prove this.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I changed question including more details.